# Why LinkedBlockingQueue's head is not private?

Tags: java, blockingqueue

I'm reading LinkedBlockingQueue code (JDK8u), and I find LinkedBlockingQueue's head field is not private, but last field is private. I can't find any particular opration with head . So why not set head to private ?

```
/**
 * Head of linked list.
 * Invariant: head.item == null
 */
transient Node<E> head;

/**
 * Tail of linked list.
 * Invariant: last.next == null
 */
private transient Node<E> last;
```

Comment: Cite your source.

Comment: Looks like head is only package level. Probably other Class in the same package is accessing head, being a low level API, they would not create any unnecessary overhead by making this private

Answer (score 5):

First some facts.

1. In Java 6, the `head` field is `private`.
2. By Java 17, the `head` field is package private ... and it has the comment about invariants.
3. The change actually happened in Java 8.

So *why* did they change it?

Well I haven't been able to figure that out so far, but possible reasons might include:

- So that subclasses (in the same package) can access the field, though I can't see any such classes in the published code base.
- To make it easier to test the class.  (This is not a *good* reason to make this change, and I can't see any evidence that this is the reason.)
- It is a "personal style" thing related to inner classes, though I'm not convinced.  (Why just do it for `head`?  Why not `tail` as well?)
- It happened by accident.

After spending a 20 minutes of so looking at the history on Github, I think it was probably an accident.  The change appears to have happened in this commit (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/commit/6f31fa54ac050d781656d6e8ed18a40b55ef5c0d) ... according to "git blame".  But when I look what is in the commit, I can't see the change at all, let alone the purpose<sup>1</sup>.  It is baffling.

Maybe it is clearer in the Mercurial history<sup>2</sup>.

At any rate, this whole thing is an exercise in curiosity.  It doesn't matter why they changed it, and it doesn't affect any user code that they did<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - The changeset description says that it is just syncing up with a private repo maintained by the original / primary author of the `java.util.concurrent` classes.

2 - We are looking a read-only Git mirror of the definitive Mercurial repository. It is possible that something has gotten screwed up in the creation of the mirror.

3 - ... modulo interaction with Heisenbugs already present in the user's code.</sup>

Comment: Why is it used in this way when other classes can access the mentioned field through other options such as _property_ or _method_? I think the reason for this use may be to meet `performance requirements`.

Comment: Well, that seems unlikely to me.  I cannot find any class in `java.util.concurrent` that refers to the `head` field, either directly or via a getter.

Comment: Thanks ! I did find all head usage scene before question and could't find any other class in the same package use it except its inner class. So eager to find out why because other fileds are private and  head is so eye-catching and wired.  Of course,it's my fault to question without mentioning jdk' version(the code i see is jdk8u really) and digging out commit history.

Answer (score 0):

I examined the [`LinkedBlockingQueue.java`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java) file in the [`jdk7u`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/) source code and saw that both fields (`head`, `last`) are naturally defined as hidden. This is a commonly used technique in programming languages based on *OOP* to prevent direct client access to fields. [Relevant lines of code](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#L140) are available below:

```java
/**
 * Head of linked list.
 * Invariant: head.item == null
 */
private transient Node<E> head;

/**
 * Tail of linked list.
 * Invariant: last.next == null
 */
private transient Node<E> last;
```

Coming to your question, it's possible that you come across different uses when browsing from a different source. However, you are always responsible for questioning and investigating its reliability. I recommend looking at more sources to get good code practices.

Comment: Sercan -- You are looking at an old copy of the source code.  The latest OpenJDK code does indeed declare `head` as package private.  The change is in the jdk8u code base onwards.  (There is an old English saying about "the pot calling the kettle black" that seems apropos ...)

Comment: Sorry. I'm not very experienced with Java. I think the correct file is in [this link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java). The reason for this problem is partly in the user who asked the question. Because if he shared the link, I wouldn't be deceived like this and I wouldn't feel the need to check again.